# what is the use of show_in_app action in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am new to use of [**rails_admin**](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) for admin panel. I have some code in **config/initializers/rails_admin.rb**

```
config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app # what is the use of this action?

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end
```

I came to know what is the use of above actions except `show_in_app` action. I have already done googling but everywhere I found it's code. I couldn't found any well described document. Can you please explain me use of this action? I have checked by `commenting` and `un-commenting` that line but no difference found in `localhost:3000/admin/` UI.

Already Checked:

- [Github](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/show_in_app.rb)
- [Ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/r/rails_admin-lbgraham-0.4.2/RailsAdmin/Config/Actions/ShowInApp.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Show in app` is a show link opens the item you are listing or editing in the backend in the frontend, it usually has an eye icon in the actions next to the items.

[image: show in app link]

When you click this button, it will redirect you to the show path of the item in the frontend

Comment: So you mean that it is use to show item?? Then why there is separate action called show? Sorry still not understood clearly..

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I've my rails_admin in different subdomain then my www and want to open urls in www version from show_in_app action, also I'm using friendly_id, how can I customize this action because as of now it returns 404 and it uses numeric ids instead of slug.